# How can I output single channel pixel data in Core Image?

Tags: ios, image-processing, filter, histogram, core-image

I'm creating a `CIImage` composed of single channel float data (where each value is a 32 bit float, but the data itself is not color data).

I'm creating this image altogether by building the buffer and wrapping it with an NSData object.  I then store that NSData object in a NoSQL object store and retrieve it later and create the CIImage using `+[CIImage imageWithBitmapData]` with format `kCIFormatRf`.

When creating the CIContext to put the CIImage through my custom filter, I thought that I would need to set the `kCIContextWorkingFormat to kCIFormatRf` (as this format considers each pixel to be a 32 bit float red 'single' component).  Though when I do this, I see an error message when trying to run the filter.

> CIContext workingformat must be kCIFormatBGRA8, kCIFormatRGBA8,
>   kCIFormatRGBAh or nil. Ignoring request for Rf.

I set the working and output color spaces to null, so that the data isn't changed in any way.

The kernel itself just outputs the current pixel, e.g. `return sample(s, samplerCoord(s))`.

But the data that comes out is not the data that went in.  It's as if each float in the output has all 4 components written to it.  But I want the output to effectively be single channel, just return the float of the first component.

Is this possible?  It must be since CIAreaHistogram can output single channel data.

Comment: `It's as if each float in the output has all 4 components written to it` I dont use iOS but shouldn't that be integers not floats? (floats can have decimal points etc which pixel colours dont have). Even if you get some RGBA output, well each component only uses 8-bits so you could do "bit-shifting" to extract a value made of first 8-bits (red) or second 8-bits (green) etc etc.. There's always some code lying around on google (esp from the C# or Java side) showing how to handle the numbers in a `For` loop. Since bitmap data is universal it should be easy to re-write for iOS.

Comment: Hi, yes colors should be discrete, though when using OpenCV to produce histograms, they seem to only want to come our as floats.  I think it can be overridden, but this would require other areas in my code to change to not assume floats.  Additionally, the Core Image in iOS allows for images to not just be pixel data (elevation maps).  Unfortunately, looping on the CPU is arduous for the amount of the image data this app processes.  Core Image parallelizes the operations, and the working format type defines Rf (1 float pixel), though the rendering context doesn't accept it.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Actually, no.  Any pixel format ending in 'f' or 'h' (like OP mentioned kCIFormatRf & kCIFormatRGBAh) are floating point.

It sounds like kCIContextWorkingFormat only accepts 3 values: "The default working format is kCIFormatRGBA8 for CPU rendering and kCIFormatRGBAf for GPU rendering. For greater color precision, GPU rendering also supports the kCIFormatRGBAh format, but this format requires twice as much memory and can be used only with color management enabled.

"https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/kcicontextworkingformat

Note this is only the *working* format.

Comment: @ScottMcKenzie: OP's question answered on the official dev forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26334